# Passing system properties along with proguard configuration file to gradle proguardFile property

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard

I am trying to invoke proguard in my gradle project.

Approach1 :

Using ant.java and pass proguard.jar and its config like below

```
    ant.java(jar:"c:/proguard5.1/lib/proguard.jar",fork:true){
     arg(value: "@./proguardconf-splitjars.pro")
     sysproperty( key : "jar.dir",value : "codegen/libs")                
     sysproperty( key : "target",value : "android-28")               
     sysproperty( key : "sdk.dir",value : "C:\\android-sdk-windows")                 
    }
```

Approach2:

Using  proguardFile property in gradle file as explained in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

```
buildTypes {
     debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguardconf-splitjars.pro'
    }
   }
```

I have different property variables in proguard file, and I have to pass them while invoking proguard. I am able to pass the properties and invoke proguard with the Approach1.

Is there any way to pass the property variables with the Approach2. I have referred below links and didnt find any info pertaining to my requirement.

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/gradle
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle supports different ways to set system properties. For me the most convenient way is to specify them in the gradle.properties file like that:

systemProp.jar.dir=codegen/libs

For example for one of the properties in your ant example.

See also the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties)